# Can't switch my Bluetooth headset to A2DP by default

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 16.04, headset

Every time I try to connect my Bluetooth headset (SHB7150) the sound option is switched to HSP by default. If I try to change to A2DP, the sound config window switch and I cannot play any type of media in any type of program or browser. They too change to the first sound device of my laptop (internal speakers) every time I try to manually change to A2DP.

Comment: Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working/775524?noredirect=1#comment1181627_775524 (wild guess, because you do not give information about ubuntu version, driver, hardware, whatever)